# Prob. 4, Chap. 5 in Baby Rudin: The existence of a solution in $(0, 1)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, derivatives

Here is Prob. 4, Chap. 5 in the book *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* by Walter Rudin, 3rd edition:

> If $$ C_0 + \frac{C_1}{2} + \cdots + \frac{C_{n-1}}{n} + \frac{C_n}{n+1} = 0,$$ where $C_0, \ldots, C_n$ are real constants, prove that the equation 
>   $$ C_0 + C_1 x + \cdots + C_{n-1}x^{n-1} + C_n x^n = 0$$ 
>   has at least one real root between $0$ and $1$.

My Attempt:

> Let $f$ be the real function defined on $[0, 1]$ by the equation $$f(x) \colon=  C_0 x + \frac{C_1 x^2 }{2} + \cdots + \frac{C_{n-1} x^n}{n} + \frac{C_n x^{n+1} }{n+1}. $$
>   Then $f(0) = 0$, and also $f(1) = 0$, by our hypothesis. Moreover, $f$ is continuous on $[0, 1]$ and differentiable on $(0, 1)$. So by the Mean Value Theorem there is a point $p \in (0, 1)$ such that 
>   $$ f(1) - f(0) = (1-0) f^\prime(p),$$
>   that is, there is a point $p \in (0, 1)$ such that 
>   $$ f^\prime(p) =  C_0 + C_1 p + \cdots + C_{n-1} p^{n-1} + C_n p^n = 0,$$ 
>   as required.

Is this proof correct?

Comment: Looks good to me. Note that this particular instance of the mean value theorem is also known as Rolle's theorem.

Comment: It is exactly same, but you can also use mean value theorem about integral.

Comment: It is perfectly correct.

Comment: @See-WooLee I would be grateful if you could please write out a detailed answer using the mean value theorem for integrals.

Comment: Mean value theorem for integral is the following : for any continuous function $f:[a, b]\to \mathbb{R}$ there exists $c\in (a, b)$ such that 
$$ f(c)=\frac{1}{b-a}\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx.$$
Now consider $f(x)=c_{0}+c_{1}x+\cdots +c_{n}x^{n}$ and $[a,b]=[0,1]$.